Intuition behind g variable calculation in the original word2vec implementation
I am trying to develop the intuition of word2vec training.
Looking into the word2vec source code, I see (for example, in skip-gram):
for (c = 0; c < layer1_size; c++) f += syn0[c + l1] * syn1[c + l2];

which calculates the dot product between last_word embedding (syn0) and word trained to be predicted (syn1). Taking into account that syn0 is addressed with hot-point input and this just copies a row of a hidden layer matrix of the network as layer's results, I assume that this dot product is just a distance between words and intended to represent a probability for the next word follow the previous one. Please, correct me if I am wrong here.
The question comes with the variable g which is calculated in the following way:
g = (1 - vocab[word].code[d] - f) * alpha; 

and I am lost here. The vocab[word].code[d] is the Huffman code (left and right, zero and one), so what’s the value of the 1 - vocab[word].code[d], it just inverts left to right and vice versa, which doesn’t have any meaning, since it should be not relevant what exactly to learn, this is just an agreement. Where is this “reflection” used?
My understanding is that we want to be vocab[word].code[d] (actual turn in in Huffman tree) and f (calculated turn in Huffman tree) is as close as possible and at the same time syn0 and syn1 weights move closer/farther (cosine dist) to fit this.
If this understanding is correct, how the code below could help us do so? If the difference vocab[word].code[d] - f is zero, the g value will be 1 and will lead to significant weights advancements. So, why do we have this "1-..." here?
To put in a nutshell, if g is a learning gradient, what is the intuition behind it? Why if f and g are calculated in this way, g would have the value which should be later multiplied to train the neural network?
I read the word2vec Parameter Learning Explained, but can’t find the justification there.
I see some helpful derivations in the article What is word2vec and how to build it from scratch? where the same structure (1-x) comes in the gradient calculations, but in a slightly different context.
Can you please help me to grasp the internal logic here?
Update
Not sure if it gives the real answer, so I don't post it as the answer so far, but it seems that it comes from the formula [51] from the word2vec Parameter Learning Explained in hierarchical softmax, where (in a very simplified way) we have something like:
$$x_{new}=x-kx$$
which could be rewritten as
$$x_{new}=(1-k)x$$
where from this (1-k) comes.
Any thoughts if this is a correct insight or there is some other explanation?
Update 2
As a second thought, the root cause could be in the sigmoid function used in calculation of 'f' and the fact that sigmoid derivative is:
$$\sigma'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\sigma(x)=\sigma(x)(1-\sigma(x))$$
Actually, this could be the same as in the first update, just in math terms.
The problem is that in the absence of the documentation on word2vec it is hard to say for sure; some sources even suggest that when the Huffman code should be 0, the f should be 1 and vice versa which confirms my first guess about "mirroring".

word2vec works well even in low dimensions and with small vocabularies, so you can build a model very quickly. So to train intuition you could also try experiments to see what breaks if you change things, or experiment with different values of alpha.

@DarrenCook, thanks for the input. The 'alpha' training speed parameter is out of the question, it is obvious. Of course, I will do some tracing. The goal is to save some time, having some high level idea and intuition instead of spending time in tracing. In my experience statistical algorithms are hard to grasp even on a small amount of data since with dozens of words it works differently and with thousands it becomes hard to analyze. And seeing how it works only always means understanding why it works. That's my question about.

I was right in my assumption that
1 - vocab[word].code[d]

just inverts the codes for left and right branches. It would have been important if one had to use the resulting syn1 matrix (for next lexem generation, etc.). But since in word2vec we are interested in syn0 matrix only (which is embeddings), this "mirroring" is totally irrelevant or exceeding. Seems to be a rudiment of some code changes done by the authors while working on code.
I tested this on sample texts and got the same embeddings for
g = (1 - vocab[word].code[d] - f) * alpha; 

and
g = (vocab[word].code[d] - f) * alpha; 

If you are going to run the same test, don't forget to replace expTable array with real function calculation, otherwise the results would differ because sampling precision issues.
If any concerns/additions, please comment.
